# how to establish TCP/IP client server communication in two different language?

Tags: php, c, server, gsm, tcp

My client side code is in C and i am sending "hello" message to server using TCP/IP protocol.and i want to create server side code in PHP. is this possible?i am using GSM module as client machine and server is in remote place.

Comment: TCP/IP is standardized. If you send a TCP message the receiving end will be able to read it unless there's an error. The programming language is irrelevant, as is the hardware involved.

Comment: Using ip address and port number i have send some message to server but i dont know where it goes in server means is there any file or path in server to read that message,sorry if this sounds stupid i don't know much about tcp ip protocol. Thanks

Comment: Then I suggest you first read a tutorial. There are thousands on the Internet, and I'll bet you could easily find some for PHP as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a very simple PHP server on the command line to check if your communication is being received - see here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

For your case, send your message from the client to the IP address of the server you run the PHP cmd line server on and to a given port, say 8000.

Your server set up then, assuming you have installed PHP and then gone to the '~/public_html' directory, simply:

> php -S localhost:8000

Make sure the number at the end, which is the port the server will listen for communication on, matches the port your server is sending the messages to.

You will be able to see on your console (your terminal window you entered the cmd above in) a note of all messages received. They will look something like this:

> [Thu Jul 21 10:48:50 2011] ::1:39147 GET /yourScriptOrPageName.html - Request read